# Using hook_form_alter to change from text filter to checkboxes

Tags: views, forms

I'm using a custom module and `hook_form_alter` to change a Views Exposed Filter from a text field to checkboxes. When altering to a select list, the module works fine. However, when I change the form type to "checkbox", the filter renders as a single checked checkbox without a label. I thought I had solved it earlier by simply removing the #size line, but after reverting the code and trying to fix it that way again, it's no longer fixing it. Any idea what I need to change?

Working select list code:

```
function dropdown_bartab_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $field_id = 'field_venue_bar_tab';

  // Only alter forms with the necessary field
  if (isset($form[$field_id .'_value'])) {

// Build a query to get all node ids having the specified field
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$results = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
                  ->fieldCondition($field_id, 'value', 'NULL', '!=')
                  ->fieldOrderBy($field_id, 'value', 'ASC')                   
                  ->execute();

// Attach the field values to the nodes
$nodes = $results['node'];
field_attach_load('node', $nodes, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $field_id));

// Add a default so the filter is optional
$options = array(
    '' => 'Any',
    '0' => 'Drinks',
    '1' => 'Food',
    );

// Alter the field
$form[$field_id .'_value']['#type'] = 'select';
$form[$field_id .'_value']['#options'] = $options;
$form[$field_id .'_value']['#size'] = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mrweiner, it's been a while since you've posted this, but does this work with Drupal 7? Also, is the $field_id the text box input ID? If so, this doesn't seem to do anything for me. Your help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Heya! I was using D7 at the time so it is D7 code,  and I'd wager that $field_id is the ID of the field itself, not the input box ID. So, the field name as it is on your content type.

Comment: Thanks a million for the response! I just got it working as a select box, but it is super slow. Page loads and query times are now taking about 8X longer. Did you experience that issue? Also, when changing to "checkboxes" as suggested, no results can be found, even with the "Any" selected, (unlike the select box which seems to query fine, just SUPER SLOW to the point that this is unusable!)

Comment: No problem. As for the

Comment: As for the? (lol) Page loads / queries are taking about a minute each... have you experienced that? I really want to use this script but that's going to be a deal breaker if there is no fix :(

Comment: Mrweiner, did you intend to type more? All I see is "As for the."

Comment: Rest of the message didn't make it through, but sorry, no idea why the query would be taking longer. I don't believe I had that issue. It's been a really long time so can't really offer any more details on what happened with my implementation. Sorry! Don't see why this would affect query time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I changed nothing, but it suddenly started working again. Must have been some strange bug.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use #type `checkboxES` (uppercase only for emphasis ;)), which is a list of checkboxes. checkbox is just a single checkbox that can either be checked or not, it can't have multiple options, so that property is ignored.

Comment: That's what I thought too. But for some reason, replacing checkboxES gives me a WSOD.

Comment: Well, WSOD just means that there was a PHP fatal error somewhere, see http://drupal.org/node/158043/ for how to find out the actual error. Probably something as simple as a wrong property/value in the form element.

Comment: It's returning "Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in ..." I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: dpm() the form element and provide a screenshot, My guess would be that #default_value is a string, try changing it to an array. Look at the other properties for other wrong values.

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but I've been lost on the dpm() thing whenever I read about it. From what I understand, I need devel enabled, right? But if it's white-screened, I wouldn't be able to access that anyway.

Comment: Yes, you need devel.module. It's extremely useful for debugging, you want to use it, trust me :) Yes, but you could comment out the #type change and then look at it. It also provides dd(), which writes to a drupal_debug.txt file in your temporary directory, that even works when there's a fatal error later on the page.

Comment: I changed the #type back to 'select' since that's what was working. But, when I try to execute dpm($form) I get a parse error. Maybe I don't understand how to run it.

Comment: Again, sorry for not knowing what I'm doing. I realized that I'm supposed to place dpm($theme) into the actual module (duh). I placed it in there, but the messages that are returning are all empty.

Comment: And it just started working, for no apparent reason. Sorry for wasting your time. But, thanks for the help!